# Image inside button is cut off only when using Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a button and inside it i have an image and a separator.
The html code is as follows:

```
<button class="uiImageButton" id="btFactors" style="flex:1 1 0px;" type="button">
  <img id="btFactorsImgID" style="vertical-align: bottom;" src="">
  <div class="uiImageButtonSeperator">Factors/Formulas</div>
</button>
```

And the css:

```
.uiImageButton {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0px;
    border-color: #007AC3;
    background-color: white;
    color: #007ac3;
    text-align: left;
    height: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Muli-Light;
}

.uiImageButtonSeperator {
    border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding-left: 4px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

The problem I am facing with is that when viewing the page in Internet explorer the image inside the button is being cut off (The image is being placed at the bottom of the button and some of it is cut off).
When using Chrome it looks fins...
I also found that when adding this line of code to the class `uiImageButton`

```
display: flex;
```

it gives a result that is close to what I`m trying to get but not close enough.

It would be great if someone can explain why I`m having this problem only in IE and also how to fix it properly.

Comment: Can u create a demo? I can't reproduce a bug https://jsfiddle.net/6y26r9jv/

Comment: ok I recreated it : https://jsfiddle.net/w4hjpz7o/   please open this with IE

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. In what way is the image cut off? It doesn't have a src in the example, so it's not visible. And when I put in an src, it shows up perfectly fine, at least if it's smaller than the height of the button. So, to repeat, what are you trying to achieve (that cannot be done by simply removing the height restriction from the button)?

Comment: I now see i was not very clear, sorry. The text "Factors/Formulas" is what actually being cut off. I also don`t want to change the height property and leave it as is. when adding the "display: flex;"  property it works ok. i just want to understand why do i need to add this property or if there is another/better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the problem is.

Just use this code to make a button. No flexbox, no additional styles and wraps. And perfectly works with IE.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1z5hhh76/).

```css
.button {
  /* no specific styles needed */
  background: blue;
}

.button__image {
  display: inline-block; /* to be on one line with text */
  width: 10px; /* don't forget sizes for your image */
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.button__text {
  font-size: 3em; /* just for fun */
  vertical-align: middle; /* set image to vertical center */
}
```

```html
<button class='button'>
  <img class='button__image' src='http://i.imgur.com/jB0PDw1.png'>
  <span class='button__text'>Factors/Formulas</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, i see this works. i would also like to know why the code here https://jsfiddle.net/w4hjpz7o/  doesn't work in IE (it cuts the text) i only want to know the reason so i would learn from it.

Comment: @itay312 Because `src` attr of image is empty and it doesn't have any sizes. To fix it, fill `src` attr and set width and height for your image.